# Dockerized Spring Boot app can't connect to database container

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I have a basic Spring Boot application with gradle and Hibernate which makes calls to an Oracle database, the database being in a docker container.

I created a Docker image of the spring boot application with the plugin "com.google.cloud.tools.jib" and using the following command:

```
./gradlew jibDockerBuild --image=app1
```

I already created a user-defined network ( let's call it **my_network** ) and I've attached the database container to the above mentioned network.

I have a docker-file in which even though I specify the image as an service and use **my_network** when I run I hit the "docker-compose up" command in CMD I receive the following exception:

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
```

The docker-compose file is the following:

```
version: '3.7'

networks:
    my_network:
        external: 
            name: my_network

services:
   app1:
   image: "app1"
   ports:
     - "9090:9090"
   environment: 
     SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:32769/ORCLPDB1.localdomain"
     SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: username
     SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: password 
   networks:
     - my_network
```

Tried solutions but with no result:

1. Specified database as service so basically let it be created the first time I hit "docker-compose up" and in service app1 specified the tag depends_on but the database container created would be in a health:starting state long after the app1 had been started and crashed
2. Let the network be created inside from the docker-compose file but same behavior as in the asked question
3. Replaced localhost with **host.docker.internal** in the database url but it said is was an unknown host

Comment: So does the DB container ever properly start up at all?

Comment: @daniu When I don't specify the database as service in the docker-compose file, yes it starts up properly

Comment: replace `@localhost:32769` with your `Oracle Database container` name as well as `port number`.

Comment: @malverndongeni so basically : jdbc:oracle:thin:@ORA12201_1/ORCLPDB1.localdomain  ? ( ORA12201_1  ) being the container name ? If I understand that correctly than it will give me the exception saying that isn't a valid database url

Comment: try this `environment:
                - DATABASE_HOST=ORA12201_1
                - DATABASE_USER= username
                - DATABASE_PASSWORD= password
                - DATABASE_NAME= NameOfYourDatabase
                - DATABASE_PORT= 32769`

Comment: @malverndongeni Still not working. But side question not necessarily related to topic: is it possible to create a container from an image and how ?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your Docker-compose file. Create Oracle Database container then your API container as follows

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  oracle-database:
      image: Your oracleImage
      environment:
         //define your oracle db settings..eg default password,users etc
      volumes:
            - /data/oracle
      ports:
        - 127.0.0.1: 32769:32769/tcp

  api1:
    image: api1
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:9090:9090/tcp
    depends_on:
     - oracle-database
    environment:
       - DATABASE_HOST=oracle-database
       - DATABASE_USER= username
       - DATABASE_PASSWORD=password
       - DATABASE_NAME= NameOfYourDatabase
       - DATABASE_PORT= 32769
```

Comment: I tried your approach and using as image : container-registry.oracle.com/database/enterprise:12.2.0.1  but gives the following errors : oracle-database_1  | /home/oracle/setup/configDBora.sh: line 161: echo: write error:

Comment: please share full error. Try this run oracle image alone ,then try to connect to your image using SQL developer

Comment: oracle-database_1  | /home/oracle/setup/configDBora.sh: line 206: /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/admin/ORCLCDB/tnsnames.ora: No such file or directory               lsnrctl: error while loading shared libraries: libclntsh.so.12.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory