# Connect to mysql in a docker container from the another container spring boot

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, docker

I've created a sql server container who's actually working. I've tried to connect my spring boot application to it and it's work.

So now, I'm trying to build the spring boot application:

```
docker build -f Dockerfile -t mySBApi .
```

done.

Then, I'm trying to run it:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 mySBApi
```

and I've this message:

> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds
> ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

Here's my .properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=mySBApi 
spring.datasource.username=SA
spring.datasource.password=srongPASSWORD75*
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

and just in case my Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:15
ADD target/mySBApi-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar mySBApi.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "mySBApi.jar"]
```

Another point: if I try to connect to the database from docker with this it's works too '-' :

```
docker exec -it sqlserver /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P strongPASSWORD75*
```

So, I can use the sql container from outside docker, but I can't if I run my spring boot container who perfectly works from outside..... What do you think about this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally change the solution and use the container's ip instead localhost or the name of the container.

Just in case someone come here because he has some problem with sql server:

I has a lot of problem to configure it, trying to log from SSMS, a lot a frustration.
Don't ask me why but everything has been done in 5min when I decided to stop the sql server on my local machine...

So one more time here's my steps if it can help:

1- stop sql server
2- create the sql container
3- try to connect to it from outside docker (with intelliJ)
4- push the middle container and adjust the .properties for docker

Angular has been push just after in less than 2min, a pleasure!

Comment: It seems the containers were not linked to each other. You could have used --link while running your spring boot container and link it to your mysql container. example: docker run --name mySBApi --link mysqlContainer -p 8080:8080 mySBApi

Comment: Oh I didn't see this method. Thanks a lot, it'll help for sure. For the moment, I just have a middle and a front but I've to cut them in 10 microservices... Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The following solutions might also help

[Docker: can't connect Spring Boot & MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61167859/docker-cant-connect-spring-boot-mysql/61186369#61186369)

[Mysql Connection Error In Docker with Spriing boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61161626/mysql-connection-error-in-docker-with-spriing-boot/61178612#61178612)

[Cannot connect MySQL with Spring Boot in docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61361535/cannot-connect-mysql-with-spring-boot-in-docker-compose/61369077#61369077)

[Dockerized Spring Boot app can't connect to database container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60051360/dockerized-spring-boot-app-cant-connect-to-database-container/60053250#60053250)